# Gradient descent - no way to find the global optimum if the model is stuck at local optima?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, regression, gradient-descent

When I was learning about gradient descent a few minutes ago, I looked at the equation[image: gradient descent algorithm]
This is supposed to find the slope of a point on the cost function J(θ<sub>0</sub>, θ<sub>0</sub>), and then go in the opposite direction of that with size of step = α.

Maybe after a few iterations, or many, or none at all, it finds itself at the local optima, it is at slope = 0 and finds that going in any direction won't help change θ<sub>j</sub>. But what if, after a while, it finds a value for the cost function that's even lower than this? Is there no way gradient descent can find out the *global* optimum?

Edit: I was thinking about this, and I thought of something that doesn't *quite* solve the problem, but might help a little in practice, which is running this until it reaches a global minimum, then pushing this to some data structure, say, a hashmap/dictionary with the initialized value and the cost function value of the local optima, and continue doing this for some while, and then find the minimum cost function value in that hashmap/array. This probably would lead the hashmap/array to contain different local optima, and then finding the best match in that would hopefully give a better result (I realize this is going to be *very* computation-hungry if the dataset is huge).

Comment: Hints:  Why do you think that once GD has reached a minimum, there will even be an "after a while"?   Why wouldn't it stop at the minimum?  How, given that the gradient equals zero, would it move away from the minimum?

Comment: Gradient descent minimizes to local values. Sometimes one can use multiple starting values to find a global result, and sometimes the algorithm will fail. That depends on the problem type, for example, if the problem is non-convex gradient methods may not be useful. Nelder-Mead or other more global search methods that also work for non-convex problems may be needed. Like they say in Maine, "Can't get they-ahh from hee-yahhhh."